# Как выполнить функцию dense_rank() с условием?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Есть такой скрипт:

```
UPDATE public.build_analyzer_objectdatanormalized normal
SET unique_code = concat_ws('.', normal.unique_code, d_rank.code)
    FROM (SELECT main.year_data
               , main.build_code
               , main.form_owner_code
               , r_normal.unique_code
               , dense_rank() OVER (ORDER BY r_normal.unique_code) code
              FROM public.build_analyzer_objectdatanormalized          r_normal
                       INNER JOIN public.build_analyzer_objectdatamain main ON r_normal.main_id = main.id
    )                                         d_rank
       , public.build_analyzer_objectdatamain main
    WHERE normal.main_id = main.id
      AND normal.unique_code = d_rank.unique_code
      AND main.form_owner_code = d_rank.form_owner_code
      AND main.year_data != d_rank.year_data;
```

В таблице `build_analyzer_objectdatanormalized`, есть `ForeginKey` на таблицу `build_analyzer_objectdatamain`, и поле `unique_code`, которое содержит значения такого формата:

```
10.13.109.75.00
10.13.109.75.00
10.13.109.75.00
10.13.152.38.120
10.13.152.38.120
```

Если в скрипте приложеном выше убрать все условия, кроме `normal.unique_code = d_rank.unique_code`, то он просто добавит ранг в конец `unique_code`.

Но мне нужно применить фильтры, чтобы за одну группу уникального кода до применения скрипта(за один ранг), считались только те записи у которых `year_data` в таблице `build_analyzer_objectdatamain` была разной. Но эти условия не срабатывают.

Мне нужно, чтобы уникальный ранг (результат функции `dense_rank`) присваивался только тогда, когда выполняется условия не соответствия объектов по годам.